# What is the name of the font used by Dymo machines?

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces

I've done some Googling and come up short. I'm looking for the name of the font used in Dymo labelling machines like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dymo-S0883980-LetraTag-LT-100H-Keyboard/dp/B0032O7J0U).

I'm after the original font (and preferably on OT version) used, or on which the letterforms used by Dymo machines are based. I'm NOT looking for [this](https://www.dafont.com/dymo.font) version that seems to be a traced version of some scanned labels. If the answer is that it's a proprietary font that isn't available in a digital form, then that's a valid answer.

Comment: Its most likely a proprietary font to avoid licensing cost. Computer connected dymos use whatever font you specify though

Comment: Agree with @joojaa - there are similar fonts, although not identical: Jura (available on Google Fonts), the Latin character set of Jasna Regular, both of which could be described as [Eurostyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurostile) variants.

Comment: Might be good to clarify exactly what you're looking for, and ideally show a sample of what you want identified. That machine is a label printer and it says it can print multiple fonts. The samples on Amazon aren't very clear, but look similar to Helvetica or Univers. If you mean the classic plastic embossing tape look, like the scan you show, that's different: it's more like Eurostile but is surely a custom design.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/drdnar/GortonDigital maybe.

"A revival of a 20th century interwar typeface.
In the early- to mid-20th century, the George Gorton Machine Company made engraving machines (among other machines). They also made a few typefaces that were often used with the machines"

Via https://mastodon.me.uk/@bbcmicrobot/111690843055144296

"Following the creation of @mwichary's book about keyboards, 'Shift Happens', has been a lot of fun over the years.

There's a Gorton Perfected Font add-on, too. You can get a taster here: https://shifthappens.site/gorton-perfected-specimen.pdf - the humble BBC Micro gets a mention early on!"

There are at least a few ttf-ifications of Gorton.  The author of the book on keyboards BBC Micro Bot is talking about apparently sells a version of the font:  https://shifthappens.site/store/

This is a very non-definitive answer, but I saw that screenshot of a keyboard and thought, hey, wait... that's the Dymo font!  Comparing it to my Dymo, it seems to match.  And it does make sense that the Dymo would use a font originally created for metal punch engraving.  Modern metal punches like https://www.lowes.com/pd/Capri-Tools-27-Piece-Professional-1-8-in-Letter-Stamp-Set/1002622250 seem to be keeping the same font, too.  More research is needed but I saw that and remembered stumbling on this question earlier so wanted to brain dump before I lost it.  It's a few years too late but maybe that's still helpful.